# foundation 6 mobile navigation in all sizes

Tags: navigation, zurb-foundation

I'm working on a project where I want to use the mobile navigation toggle for all the screen sizes. It's working so far but not in the xxlarge screen. When I remove the data-hide-for="xxlarge in title-bar div the navigation disapears completly.. 
Can anyone giv me a hint how to solve this?
Thanks!

Here is the header part of this site:

```
<header>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="large-12 columns">
            <div class="title-bar" data-responsive-toggle="main-menu" data-hide-for="xxlarge" >
              <div class="title-bar-left" >
                <div class="logoklein show-for-small-only"><a href="#"><img alt="" src="fileadmin/templates/img/logo_klein.png"> </a></div>
                <div class="logomittel show-for-medium-only"><a href="#"><img alt="" src="fileadmin/templates/img/logo_mittel.png"></a></div>
                <div class="logogross show-for-large"><a href="#"><img alt="" src="fileadmin/templates/img/logo_gross.png"></a></div>
              </div>
              <div class="title-bar-right" >
                <button class="menu-button-small show-for-small-only align-right" type="button" data-toggle><img alt="Menue öffnen" src="fileadmin/templates/img/menue_klein.png"></a></button>
                <button class="menu-button-medium show-for-medium-only align-right" type="button" data-toggle><img alt="Menue öffnen" src="fileadmin/templates/img/menue_mittel.png"></a></button>
                <button class="menu-button-large show-for-large align-right" type="button" data-toggle><img alt="Menue öffnen" src="fileadmin/templates/img/menue_gross.png"></a></button>
              </div>

              <div  id="main-menu">
                <f:cObject typoscriptObjectPath="lib.menu">
                <!--Navigation gets inserted here by CMS-->
              </f:cObject>
            </div>  <!-- Ende Titlebar-->
          </div><!-- large -12 columns-->
        </div><!-- row-->
        </header>
```

Comment: You have to use `responsive navigation` classes along with `topbar` if you are implementing topbar with 'data-hide'. I'm guessing you are partially implementing `top bar` and `responsive navigation` which is causing this glitch. Go through the documentation clearly.

Comment: Hi Hari, my navigation and the toggle is working as it should. The only things that it is not shown in xxlarge. Thanks to data-hide-for="xxlarge" There is no attribute like data-show-for ? I did not find a solution in the documentation..

Comment: If you are having the same code that you have submitted, then you have *forgot* to close `<div id="main-menu">` with a `</div>` before closing the `title-bar` div. See if that fixes the problem.

Comment: Hi, after a long time not working on this project i found an easy solution for the problem. I simply set the xxlarge breakpoint up to 5000px so it's working as it should. Thanks for helping anyway!